# Jsoup Remove the link href attribute starts with Href

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to remove the link href attribute starts with http://goo.gl to https://goo.gl .

Below is my code, but it is not exactly no error message.

I do not know what should I do.  Please help me.

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document connect = Jsoup.connect("http://blogtamsu.vn/ngoc-trinh-duoc-goi-la-hinh-mau-bao-hieu-tot-doi-dep-dao.html").get();
            Elements selects = connect.select("div.remain_detail");
            String levels = "a[href^=http://goo.gl],a[href^=https://goo.gl]";
            for (String level : levels.split(",")) {
                selects.remove(level);
            }
            System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(selects.html(), Whitelist.relaxed()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `regex` to select and remove from `selects`:

```
selects.select("a[href~=(http|https)://goo.gl]").remove()
```

Comment: I felt great my command was executed successfully by your answer.Thank you very much